# How to get array with closes subset to the target array

Tags: java, oracle, recursion, iteration

I need to find rows in array (x rows) with closest subset (less or equal) to the target array (1 row).

| Target | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Case1 | 5 | 6 |

| Target | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Case2 | 6 | 2 |

| Candidates | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Can1 | 1 | 2 |
| Can2 | 7 | 1 |
| Can3 | 1 | 0 |
| Can4 | 1 | 3 |
| Can5 | 2 | 2 |
| Can6 | 4 | 3 |
| Can7 | 0 | 1 |

Result for case1 (Target is equal to sum of candidates): Can4 & Can6.

Column A: 1 + 4 = 5

Column B: 3 + 3 = 6

Result for case2 (Target is more than sum of candidates): Can3 & Can5

Column A: 1 + 2 <= 6

Column B: 2 = 2

So only rows whose sum on both columns is less or equal should be included. If best result is not found (sum of candidates matches target) than rows which are closest to target should be included.

I have found a solution with oracle recursive query, but performance was not optimal when there was a larger data set and I did not found a way to transfer it to iterative code.

If someone has an idea how to do it with iteration in either java or PL/SQL I would be really grateful.

Comment: Even with a single column of values, the problem requires exponential time if you require the exact answer (the absolute best, optimal combination of cans). There are heuristic approaches that return a "good" answer, but not necessarily the "best" answer, in much more reasonable time. For the problem in two dimentions (two "value" columns) it is not even clear what you mean by "closest". Minimize the sum of shortfalls? The sum of SQUARES of shortfalls? Or something else?

Comment: Closest would be greatest SUM of candidates.

Answer (score 1):

### Brute Force

The combination problem can be solved using brute force in exponential time and space

> n * 2<sup>n</sup>

The approach

1. generates all the subsets
2. selects only the valid subsets based on some criteria
3. if none of them are valid, then return empty result
4. sorts valid subsets based on some criteria
5. returns the first subset in the sorted subsets

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ClosestCombination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] inputRecords = new int[][] {
            {1, 2},
            {7, 1},
            {1, 0},
            {1, 3},
            {2, 2},
            {4, 3},
            {0, 1}
        };

        int[][] result = computeResult(inputRecords, new int[] {5, 6});
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
        result = computeResult(inputRecords, new int[] {6, 2});
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
        result = computeResult(inputRecords, new int[] {0, 0});
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }

    public static int[][] computeResult(int[][] inputRecords, int[] expected) {
        List<List<int[]>> allSubsets = generateSubsets(inputRecords);

        List<List<int[]>> candidates = allSubsets.stream()
            .filter(subset -> isAcceptable(subset, expected))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // if the none of the subsets are valid, then return empty result
        if (candidates.size() == 0) {
            return new int[0][0];
        }

        // reverse sort
        candidates.sort((a, b) -> {
            int v1 = normalize(a);
            int v2 = normalize(b);
            // if the values are same, then pick smaller size
            return v1 == v2 ? a.size() - b.size() : v2 - v1;
        });
        List<int[]> result = candidates.get(0);
        return result.toArray(new int[0][0]);
    }

    // add custom value generation as per business meaning of "closest"
    private static int normalize(List<int[]> subset) {
        return subset.stream().mapToInt(a -> a[0] + a[1]).sum();
    }

    // add custom validation check as per business meaning of "closest"
    private static boolean isAcceptable(List<int[]> subset, int[] expected) {
        int valueA = subset.stream().mapToInt(a -> a[0]).sum();
        int valueB = subset.stream().mapToInt(a -> a[1]).sum();
        return valueA <= expected[0] && valueB <= expected[1];
    }

    // generates all possible subsets (does not include the empty set)
    private static List<List<int[]>> generateSubsets(int[][] inputRecords) {
        List<List<int[]>> all = new ArrayList<>(); // holds all subsets

        for (int[] input : inputRecords) {
            // subsets generated by including the current input element
            List<List<int[]>> includedSubsets = new ArrayList<>();

            // include the current element alone
            List<int[]> current = new ArrayList<>();
            current.add(input);
            includedSubsets.add(current);

            // clone all previously computed subsets and add current element to the clones
            for (List<int[]> subset : all) {
                List<int[]> withCurrentInput = new ArrayList<>(subset);
                withCurrentInput.add(input);
                includedSubsets.add(withCurrentInput);
            }

            // add subsets generated in current iteratiion to result
            all.addAll(includedSubsets);
        }
        return all;
    }
}
```

TODO: Yet to add the DP solution to optimize on time and space

Comment: Thank you your solution returns correct result.

But if I increase int[][] inputRecords to 21 lines the performance is poor it takes around 11 seconds and with bigger array it would even more. Do you have some idea how to get better performance?

Comment: @Luka, True, this is an exponential algorithm. i will try to add the polynomial algorithm this week. Hopefully we should be able to solve in O(n^4). Still i haven't been able to formulate it.